How to cite in Latin
Can I get some help on the correct way to cite a work in Latin? I am looking for the snippets:
page
pages
p.
pp.
cited on page 15
cited on pages 15, 17, 19
cit. on p. 15
cit. on pp. 15, 17, 19

and so far I have come up with these literal translations, that I am not sure are current usage in bibliography citation.
pagina
paginae
p.
pp.
citatis pag 15
citatis pag. 15, 17, 19 .
cit. supra p. 15
cit. s., pp. 15, 17, 19

Would someone, confirm this, correct it, or point me to the right direction or some work where I can see any material on this or examples?
